# How do nicely concat asynchronous network requests in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, networking, asynchronous

I want to make a series of network requests (in Qt) in which the details of one request depends on the result of the last one. Currently my code looks like this:

```
QNetworkReply *reply = m->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://qt-project.org")));
    reply->connect(reply,&QNetworkReply::finished,[=](){
        //Do something with reply, calculate a value for the next request
        QNetworkReply *reply2 = m->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://www.google.de")));
        reply->deleteLater();
        reply2->connect(reply2,&QNetworkReply::finished,[=](){
            //Do something with reply2, calculate a value for the next request
            QNetworkReply *reply3 = m->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://amazon.de")));
            reply2->deleteLater();
            reply3->connect(reply3,&QNetworkReply::finished,[=](){
                //...
            });
        });
    });
```

While this works, I see two problems:

1. The code gets really ugly when I want to concat more requests.
2. How do I do error handling? I can not use throw.

So I am looking for a way to structure this code better. I have thought of the following options:

(1) Use blocking requests, one could simple write (pseudocode!):

```
try {
    ResultType res1 = blockingRequest("http://qt-project.org");
    // Doe something with res1
    ResultType res2 = blockingRequest("http://www.google.com");
    // Doe something with res2
    ResultType res3 = blockingRequest("http://amazon.de");
    // Doe something with res3
catch(...) {
    // ...
}
```

This code must then run in a separate thread. I read that blocking requests are difficult to do in Qt, and I would prefer to stick to the standard Qt way of doing things.

(2) Use macros, or some other mechanism, to write better looking code.
I am thinking of the "do" Syntax in haskell. I have done this before in Haxe with [MonadSurprise](https://github.com/RudolfVonKrugstein/haxe-monads/blob/master/monads/MonadSurprise.hx). Using this in Haxe I can write:

```
MonadSurprise.dO({
    res1 <= request("http://qt-project.org");
    res2 <= request("http://www.google.de");
    res3 <= request("http://amazon.de");
});
```

MonadSurprise.dO is a macro which takes care of concating the Surprises (returned by request) properly. It also takes care of error handling by stoping the complete operation and returning the error when one occurs.

But I have no Idea if something like this can be done in c++/qt.

Comment: Implement an asynchronous signal/slot mechanism to send and receive requests. Use a state variable to tell you which request you are currently processing.

Comment: In a slot it is also possible to ask for the `sender()`.

Comment: @owacoder can you elaborate? I don't see how this would simplify the code ...

Comment: @Nathan - Create a slot called when initializing the request chain and when the last request finishes. Check the reply of the last request, and start a new one accordingly. This simplifies the request chain into a single `replyFinished` function, instead of nested `if`s.